Shiny App Deployment: The write operation timed out
I am currently working on a data science project for university. My team have designed an app in shiny in python (not in R). I am having issues during the deploying stage as "The write operation timed out". The full error message is at the end of the post. I don't seem to have this issue when working at univeristy (using the university wifi system).
The app currently has around 10GB worth of csv data files (it's alot I know haha).
I have tried using both the command prompt and ubuntu terminal. Both methods give me the same error.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Full error message belwo:
Deploying bundle ...    [ERROR]: Exception trying to connect to https://shinyapps-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/bundles/application-11939862/1c0e23140903498b91275dec394db8f0.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA54P7SCTKTTKAXS5B&Signature=kb6NTv%2B1gr%2FEGfFxkZeeGLkeTz8%3D&content-md5=%2FWYw9klxHxhboSwJpWJNfw%3D%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-tar&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDfE2vT87S34QIl%2BKu6lJ1zG8FrFNyoRnMVStCGjRGT9QIhAN5%2BeMXC9k1lopKFGyU6dvFRkow6i%2BBuUiJ9YUD5Gy%2BrKoMFCEIQABoMOTU0NTU1NTY5MzY1IgxFPE2fuilezyfS2wkq4ARp2OuWwVQ53UPaj6B6K9KI%2FvUUPxI2uMH2F5VuuvreHCDjiyuiK3Eoo5E5VbhSheDOZi%2F1w%2BKWQpaKwsIoiaGBp637H7otXLC9KycGiS98v3yPxm0IHABRl1Z9%2Fxe7eBkZDklj8IS5uVX1lcCTBWVyyh0z2wt7Ni2%2BDhk1TyK9lFUX5fhHOwEIJHnfpK13RpjocJna5EfCdYMFjsg5n12s7vIWRzQ1Deh1wntGhwyfyWqWKNRLQ5DSs2XVZrUyRvysUCwXMmMa1PDCkrOwfMkjJnzXWTotAtjmI7wBCMYwoBwDdykD0ycJgtCadhDpOu6jM1%2BodvzukHL4%2F0znYhiAVNlwpR4jsiG%2FO5sYVuGZpiWE0DiqF9%2F1IFQ0xr%2FkX%2BtfRPzqI9bYAQQk%2F6vhmtUQxivKH5rX4YdBDKEjwjBF3%2B%2B3ti%2F0ebz%2BTVR6k9DJp%2FJmtGAw6hx4WJDKI%2BDNKl%2F7TvkCFfP2%2BhZIvtau7UtvxBFvzWDX6D63QSvyDv1%2Fr8uLk267hyG5duwLtYvvI7M1qHipRhUqNAOINRzvwqqa6q%2BH9jYi5P8PnsGO7nt%2FqwKLbv%2By9nQ2sHXYJOcCTnt%2FDVWBCrzTkAiiZN%2FVCTfeqvJ13yzkThD2aNoGNm5SeYA59yuscZn3OlkOR%2FjIAaREfncB3m2DuFMsD4XfNOUOEOzoyxCAt%2B9cXgqW6epNakpeEhVne96vUBdYsYa9j7mXAAPzbk6E%2BoJMb23Diw2PB4S8lxKMJVijFC9KitJXtVXfkA4tDr3iqNb0nnvnM0kI6DbpqWgRtOEwxzWwSny8JDC%2Fu7GyBjqZAYlqkcgnaGtTAmRaaYY5CA%2BDCPYcjPdHe%2BnYun1SMgDcpEek1YCx36DwSavNw8ehudGUNfniWtwKKCWNdZ9%2BlMihFynx2UPl%2BEdxfZA%2Fvh2NhxdutpV1I7e2O2CbAJdV70fruN2YAibFx2ldeJLKzCAD2tISamc0%2FI7l5PZG8mBTL3buUjQyEYr2KvnY5ouYhgKorD9TXnS6Mw%3D%3D&Expires=1716286927 - The write operation timed out
Error: Exception trying to connect to https://shinyapps-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/bundles/application-11939862/1c0e23140903498b91275dec394db8f0.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA54P7SCTKTTKAXS5B&Signature=kb6NTv%2B1gr%2FEGfFxkZeeGLkeTz8%3D&content-md5=%2FWYw9klxHxhboSwJpWJNfw%3D%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-tar&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDfE2vT87S34QIl%2BKu6lJ1zG8FrFNyoRnMVStCGjRGT9QIhAN5%2BeMXC9k1lopKFGyU6dvFRkow6i%2BBuUiJ9YUD5Gy%2BrKoMFCEIQABoMOTU0NTU1NTY5MzY1IgxFPE2fuilezyfS2wkq4ARp2OuWwVQ53UPaj6B6K9KI%2FvUUPxI2uMH2F5VuuvreHCDjiyuiK3Eoo5E5VbhSheDOZi%2F1w%2BKWQpaKwsIoiaGBp637H7otXLC9KycGiS98v3yPxm0IHABRl1Z9%2Fxe7eBkZDklj8IS5uVX1lcCTBWVyyh0z2wt7Ni2%2BDhk1TyK9lFUX5fhHOwEIJHnfpK13RpjocJna5EfCdYMFjsg5n12s7vIWRzQ1Deh1wntGhwyfyWqWKNRLQ5DSs2XVZrUyRvysUCwXMmMa1PDCkrOwfMkjJnzXWTotAtjmI7wBCMYwoBwDdykD0ycJgtCadhDpOu6jM1%2BodvzukHL4%2F0znYhiAVNlwpR4jsiG%2FO5sYVuGZpiWE0DiqF9%2F1IFQ0xr%2FkX%2BtfRPzqI9bYAQQk%2F6vhmtUQxivKH5rX4YdBDKEjwjBF3%2B%2B3ti%2F0ebz%2BTVR6k9DJp%2FJmtGAw6hx4WJDKI%2BDNKl%2F7TvkCFfP2%2BhZIvtau7UtvxBFvzWDX6D63QSvyDv1%2Fr8uLk267hyG5duwLtYvvI7M1qHipRhUqNAOINRzvwqqa6q%2BH9jYi5P8PnsGO7nt%2FqwKLbv%2By9nQ2sHXYJOcCTnt%2FDVWBCrzTkAiiZN%2FVCTfeqvJ13yzkThD2aNoGNm5SeYA59yuscZn3OlkOR%2FjIAaREfncB3m2DuFMsD4XfNOUOEOzoyxCAt%2B9cXgqW6epNakpeEhVne96vUBdYsYa9j7mXAAPzbk6E%2BoJMb23Diw2PB4S8lxKMJVijFC9KitJXtVXfkA4tDr3iqNb0nnvnM0kI6DbpqWgRtOEwxzWwSny8JDC%2Fu7GyBjqZAYlqkcgnaGtTAmRaaYY5CA%2BDCPYcjPdHe%2BnYun1SMgDcpEek1YCx36DwSavNw8ehudGUNfniWtwKKCWNdZ9%2BlMihFynx2UPl%2BEdxfZA%2Fvh2NhxdutpV1I7e2O2CbAJdV70fruN2YAibFx2ldeJLKzCAD2tISamc0%2FI7l5PZG8mBTL3buUjQyEYr2KvnY5ouYhgKorD9TXnS6Mw%3D%3D&Expires=1716286927 - The write operation timed out
The issue is that it works at university but not at home. I'd prefer not to travel to university on days where I don't need to go because the travel is really not worth it.
I appreciate any help.
